# Use square brackets for citations with classicthesis

Tags: bibliographies, classicthesis

When using `"classicthesis"`, I get

> (Miede, 2015)

when using \citep{miede2015} in the text. However, I want the citation to have square brackets

> [Miede, 2015]

but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Since the corresponding code lines in `classicthesis-config.tex` are

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
  backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8, %instead of bibtex
  %backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
  language=auto,%
  %style=numeric-comp,%
  style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
  citestyle=apa,
  %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
  sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
  maxbibnames=3, % default: 3, et al.
  %backref=true,%
  natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
```

not very straightforward, I do not know how to implement the change of brackets.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Try adding in the preamble `\let\mkbibparens=\mkbibbrackets`

Comment: What you could do is: stop using natbib compatibility mode, and if you want to continue using `\citep` define  `\newcommand*{\citep}[1]{\mkbibbrackets{\cite{#1}}}` and `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}` for the comma between author name and year.